# Encryption on the fly for Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, encryption

I have a project Native or HTML5 Android project (I'm considering which solution right now) which is an English lessons application: you download leesons and complete them. The information download has rights and don't want to be hacked by anyone, so I want to download (maybe through web servies) and store it in a DB inside the App. Is there any encryption solution to unencrypt the access to the DB in order to avoid the hack of the lessons downloaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SQlcipher can be used to encrypt database files. It is an extension to SQLite, so I assume it to be fast.

http://sqlcipher.net/

Also check for Android,
http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: Thank you, I think it will be fit.